# Как в Джанго сделать форму с полями разных моделей?

Tags: python, django

Мне необходимо сделать одну форму с полями разных моделей.

models:

```
class Dolgnik (models.Model):

    arbitr = models.ForeignKey(
        Arbitr,
        on_delete = models.CASCADE,
        related_name = 'dolgniks',
        verbose_name = 'финансовый управляющий',
    )
    region = models.ForeignKey(
        Region,
        on_delete = models.CASCADE,
        related_name = 'dolgnik_regions',
        verbose_name = 'регион'
    )
    dolgnik_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name = 'имя должника')
    dolgnik_index = models.CharField(max_length=6, verbose_name = 'индекс')
    dolgnik_city = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name = 'город')
    dolgnik_street = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name = 'улица и дом')

    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ('', 'выберите пол должника'),
        ('М', 'мужской'),
        ('Ж', 'женский'),
    )
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, verbose_name = 'пол должника')
    end_date = models.DateField(verbose_name='дата вынесения решения о процедуре') # дата вынесения решения о процедуре
    start_date = models.DateField(verbose_name= '3 года до подачи заявления') # 3 года до подачи заявления
    num_delo = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name = 'номер дела')
    birthday = models.DateField(verbose_name='день рождения должника', blank=True, default=date.today)
    place_of_birth = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='место рождения должника', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.dolgnik_name
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('dolgnik_detail', args=[str(self.id)])

# уфнс
class Ufns (models.Model):
    region = models.ForeignKey(
        Region,
        on_delete = models.CASCADE,
        related_name = 'ufns_regions'
    )
    ufns = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ufns_index = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    ufns_city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ufns_street = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ufns

# ифнс
class Ifns (models.Model):
    region = models.ForeignKey(
        Region,
        on_delete = models.CASCADE,
        related_name = 'ifns_regions'
    )
    ifns = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ifns_index = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    ifns_city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ifns_street = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ifns

# банки
class Bank (models.Model):

    bank = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    bank_index = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    bank_city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    bank_street = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.bank
```

Используя подход ниже, я могу указать лишь один form_class .

```
class FormRequest(CreateView):
    model = Dolgnik 
    form_class = RequestForm
    template_name = 'arbitr_requests/formrequest.html'
```

Подскажите, как это осуществить.

Answer (score 1):

1. Решение - написать обертку, реализующую логику `Form`, но для 2х+ форм. Когда писал такое для связанных `ModelForm`, получилось криво, и пример смогу дать вечером только. По сути будет класс, который имитирует работу с переданными формами, вызывая одноименные методы
2. Решение - переписать `view`,  чтобы та обрабатывала 2 формы. Скорее всего придется переписать все места, где использовалась форма.
3. Если порядок полей не важен. можно посмотреть в сторону [formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/formsets/). Хотя, в шаблоне можно что угодно наворотить, главное потом не забыть и не сломать ничего

Answer (score 0):

как вариант я просто передавал обе формы в context
view.py

```
from django.views.generic import View

from .forms import SomeForm, SomeForm_1


class BaseView(View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form_1 = SomeForm
        form_2 = SomeForm_1

        context = {
                'form_1': form_1,
                'form_2': form_2,
            }
        return render(request, 'ИМЯ_ТЕПЛЕЙТ_ФАЙЛА.html', context)


    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form_1 = SomeForm(request.POST or None)
        form_2 = SomeForm_1(request.POST or None)

        if form_1.is_valid():
            new_object_in_form_1 = form_1.save(commit=False)

            new_object_in_form_1.поле модели = form_1.cleaned_data['поле модели']
            new_object_in_form_1.поле модели = form_1.cleaned_data['поле модели']
            #... и т.д.
            new_object_in_form_1.save()

        if form_2.is_valid():
            new_object_in_form_2= form_2.save(commit=False)
            
            new_object_in_form_2.поле модели= form_2.cleaned_data['поле модели']
            new_object_in_form_2.поле модели= form_2.cleaned_data['поле модели']
            new_object_in_form_2.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/') #редирект на нужный урл при удаче
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')#редирект на нужный урл при неудаче
```

**some_template.html**

```
#......
<form action="{% url 'url-name' %}" method="POST">
                      {% csrf_token %}
                      {{ form_1 }}
                      {% csrf_token %}
                      {{ form_2 }}

                      <button class="" type="submit">Отправить</button>
```

Если эти модели связаны ForeignKey, то в `def post(...)`нужно поиграться с порядком записи из формы и передачи нужного инстанса модели в нужное поле связанной модели